# SSDT for VS 2015 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I am looking for `SSDT` for `VS 2015` and according to [MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt204009.aspx) it is already implemented into the current version. But I cannot find it under the "`New Project`" Templates nor can I find it under "`Online`" in the Templates tree. Anyone knows how to get SSDT working under `VS 2015`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSDT SQL Server Database Project can be found under **New Project > Installed > Templates > Other Languages > SQL Server**. If you have installed VS2015 RC Community Edition, please make sure you have opted-in SQL Server Data Tools feature during the installation. For Enterprise Edition, SSDT is pre-selected by default and it should be installed already.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If i didnt opt-in the sql server data tools during the Installation is it possible to do that afterwards or do i have to perform a re-install?

Comment: Yes it is possible to do afterwards. Go to Control Panel > Programs and Features. Right-mouse-click on Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 RC entry then select 'Change' option. It will open up the VS setup UI. Click 'Modify' button then you will see all features that you can add or remove. By selecting the Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools check box, you can add the features to the current VS installation. There is no need to reinstall VS2015 RC itself.

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately there is noch Check Box "SQL Server Data Tools". First off I thought it is due to the community edition but https://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs say that community includes SSDT

Comment: I reinstalled VS and now I have the option you were talking about. Thanks!

Comment: Also they have renamed it and now it is "SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio". Thus it didn't show in the result when I was looking for Visual Studio only.